# Expanding Vector's Data to Specified Size (Interpolation)

Tags: c++

I need a function that takes in a vector and grows it to a new size, using interpolation (linear is fine) to fill in the data's gaps.

```cpp
function(vector<double> &vect, int newSize); //something like this
```

This is easy to do in some scenarios, but usually is messy.

**Easy:**

```cpp
vector<int> vect{ 0, 2, 4 };
newSize = 5;
function(vector<double> &vect, int newSize); //=> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

**Hard:**

```cpp
vector<int> vect{ 0, 2, 4 };
newSize = 6;
function(vector<double> &vect, int newSize); //=> ??????????????
```

On the harder scenarios I don't even know if this is a problem interpolation alone can fix, and am not sure if there is some standard convention to expand sample data like so.

Any information or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Interpolation typically involves two sequences that define the mapping of x's to y's and a third sequence of different x's that one wants estimates of y's for.  I don't understand exactly how you mean interpolation to apply here. If you could clarify with an example of how you want a sequence to be transformed. Is it just stretching a sequence with the same end points?

Comment: Usually with this kind of linear 1D-interpolation you go through the indices of the new vector and try to find the two consecutive indices of the old vector. Then you determine how much of the left and the right element should be "mixed in" to get the new value.

Comment: I am really dealing with two paired vectors, call them time and cookies. The time vector has a start and finish (time frame), and a consistent step between each index of time. The cookie vector is an experimental set of data of a scientific phenomenon that is based off of time. I have 2 calculated time and cookie vectors that are much larger than their experimental counterparts. I want to fit the experimental curve to the calculated curve, but can only do so with equal length data sets. It is very important that the time frame and step are equal between the two curves.

Comment: Gerriet, I was doing something like that but the problem was that I needed the new vector. This is possible in my scenario, since I know the step and time frame, but was wondering if there was a more basic way to solve this.

Comment: Check out this matlab function https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html . Does this do what you want if it were in C++?

Comment: @doug, not really. I am not directly dealing with functions, rather their results at given times.

Comment: I have data within a given time frame and want to expand the data's quantity to match the step of a larger data set in the same time frame, using something to estimate values.

Comment: Okay, so do you expect expanding to a size of 6 should produce something like `{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 }`?  That is my interpretation of what you mean by "interpolation", in which case the problem is straight forward to solve.

Comment: I will usually be resizing 1k-20k sized vectors into 200k-900k ones, so I am not sure what is the best convention @paddy. I want something like Lagrange to smooth the resultant curve into something closer to its more accurate counterpart.

Comment: Yeah, but are the start and end values considered _fixed points_?  Your actual requirements are unclear.  It seems that even you don't know the requirements, which means it will be impossible for you to explain them to us.

Comment: @padddy, everything in the original vector is a fixed point. When i expand the data set I want to estimate the new values, like smoothing a curve. This vector is based off of time, with i=0 being the tMin, and the end being tMax. The current time is tMin + i*dt. I already have a larger data set over the same time frame that I want to fit the smaller experimental one too, but need to expand the experimental vector in order to do so.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation is perhaps what you search for.

Comment: @Öö Tiib
That looks like what I want. Could I just input a vector and then specif how many points I want the resultant spline to be?

Comment: Spline turns your points into continuous piece-wise polynomial and from continuous line you can calculate new points.

Comment: @Öö Tiib If there is a way to control how many points are calculated within the interval(i=0 to end of original vector) then this is perfect. I need to make sure that this new experimental vector is equal my calculated vectors size.

Comment: Sure, from continuous line you can calculate points with whatever small stepping you choose.

Comment: @Öö Tiib Do most implementations allow you to control the step of the continuous line?

Comment: Continuous means by definition that there are no interruptions.

Comment: But there has to be some sort of step within the implementation, right? There can't be an infinite amount of points.

Comment: What you mean? Limit is only in precision of numbers that the programmer did choose.

Comment: The interpolation function gives you values for all possible positions. You then create your result by sampling it at the positions you are interested in.

Comment: I'm being very stupid, but how does it handle this infinite(?) amount of points. What would I reference in order to get specific points?

Comment: Then you do not understand interpolation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Answer (score 0):

I would try something similar to this:

```
std::vector<double> interpolate(const std::vector<double>& v, const unsigned newSize)
{
  assert(!v.empty());
  std::vector<double> result(newSize);
  const std::size_t oldSize = v.size();
  for (unsigned i=0; i < newSize; i++)
  {
    const unsigned idx = i*(oldSize-1) / newSize;
    const unsigned mod = i*(oldSize-1) % newSize;

    if (mod == 0)
      result[i] = v[idx];
    else
    {
      const double part = double(mod) / double(newSize);
      result[i] = v[idx]*(1.0-part) + v[idx+1]*part;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```